# Getting " NULL / Empty " values for input Text if the page remains idle in some time?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, geospatial

Getting " NULL / Empty " values for couple of times (I have typed values) in a input textbox due to idleness of web page(idleness might be the reason, Itz my Guess).

I can give names for multiple shapes by one by one. But If i have hold the webpage for 5 mins. Then I could not give a name and description for the polygon *(in the infowindow object)* at the first time. At the second time I can give a name for InfoWindow Object.But it is not getting close automatically. I have to manually close it out.  Please help me to write a error less code with Google Maps API.

Things I have done. Giving a Name and Description for each Polygon after the polygon has been drawn by the help of infoWindow Object. The code is below. Help me to find the error in my code and help me to identify the area of my poor implementation.

```
google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

var polygons = [];
var polygonShape = [];
var polygonJson = {};
var map;
var drawingTool = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager();

    function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            zoom : 4,
            center : new google.maps.LatLng(37.5499, -95.5524),
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        drawingTool.setOptions({
            drawingMode : google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
            drawingControl : true,
            drawingControlOptions : {
                position : google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                drawingModes : [ google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON ]
            }
        });
        drawingTool.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingTool, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
        if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
            createPolygon(event.overlay);
        }
    });
}

    function createPolygon(polygon) {
        polygons.push(polygon);
        this.vertices = polygon.getPath();
        var content = '<label><b>Region Name : </b></label><input type="text" size="20" id="region_name"/></br><label align="top"><b>Description : </b></label><textarea id="region_desc" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea><br/><input type="button" value="Save Region" onclick="get_point_info(vertices);"/><br/>'
            + '<b>-----INFO-----</b>';
        verticesLoop(this.vertices, content);
    }

    function get_point_info(vertices) {
        var vertice = vertices;
        var RegionName = document.getElementById('region_name').value;
        var RegionDesc = document.getElementById('region_desc').value;
        this.infoWindow.close();
        polygonJson = {
            data : vertice,
            regionName : RegionName,
            regionDescription : RegionDesc
        };
        alert(Object.toJSON(polygonJson));
    }

    function verticesLoop(vertices, content) {
        var clat = 0;
        var clng = 0;
        var contents = content;
        var vert = vertices;
        vert.forEach(function(xy, i) {
            var contentString = '<br/><b>Lat :</b> ' + xy.lat() + '<b>Long : </b>'
                + xy.lng();
            contents = contents + contentString;
            clat = xy.lat();
            clng = xy.lng();
        });
        displayInfo(contents, new google.maps.LatLng(clat, clng));
    }

    function displayInfo(conString, customPosition) {
        this.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content : conString,
            position : customPosition,
            maxWidth : 350 
        });
        this.infoWindow.open(map);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

**ERRORS:**
The values are in the textbox are getting null(sometimes) for both the textbox which was triggered by infoWindow.

Regards,
ArunRaj.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that root cause of problem is that user is allowed to draw several polygon before infowindow Region Name and Description are written and Save Region is pressed. If you draw many polygons and infowindows are opened when you click Save Region from the last one, information is sent from the first one polygon. So, if nothing is written for the first one polygon you will get empty values like:

```
Object {data: ug, regionName: "", regionDescription: ""}
```

I'd prevent drawing of polygons until information is not sent using Save Region using `drawingTool.setDrawingMode(null);`:

```
function displayInfo(conString, customPosition) {
    console.log('this');
    console.log(this);

    this.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content : conString,
        position : customPosition,
        maxWidth : 350 
    });

    drawingTool.setDrawingMode(null);

    this.infoWindow.open(map);
}
```

and enabling it again after information about name and description is collected:

```
function get_point_info(vertices) {
    var vertice = vertices;
    var RegionName = document.getElementById('region_name').value;
    var RegionDesc = document.getElementById('region_desc').value;
    this.infoWindow.close();
    polygonJson = {
        data : vertice,
        regionName : RegionName,
        regionDescription : RegionDesc
    };
    console.log('Object.toJSON(polygonJson)');
    console.log(polygonJson);

    drawingTool.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON);
}
```

Comment: Jurkovic : Hey, Really thanks for finding my mistake. But I feel, Disable and Enable the drawing tool is not a good option.   Is it a only way to do it.

Comment: It is not only option but is most probably the easiest one. 

One option is to close previous infowindow if another polygon is drawn. But in that case you have to enable click event on polygon to open infowindow again which will complicate design further because you will not be able to draw another polygon behind it.

Another option is to have one infowindow for each polygon. Now you have only one global for all of them. You will have to track state of each and process them. Something like that...

Comment: Jurkovic : Thank you so much for the lovely explanation. I got some confusion. Now I am clear. Do you find any way to reduce my code ? If yes, can you help me ?

Comment: I don't know at the moment. If I found something I'll update the answer so you'll be notified. Do you send information from infowindow to some database for later usage (Object.toJSON(polygonJson))?

Comment: Yes ofCourse. I am just making a JSON as a string.